# Can Microsoft SQL Operations Studio be used to access MYSQL database on Mac?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-data-studio

I am trying to use Microsoft SQL Operations Studio to access a MYSQL database on my local, but am receiving the following error:

Error:*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)*

Can Microsoft SQL Operations Studio be used to access MYSQL database on Mac?

Answer (score 3):

> "Can Microsoft SQL Operations Studio be used to access MYSQL database on Mac?"

No, it was designed to work with MS RDBMS. [SQL Operations Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download):

> See one of the following quickstarts to get started:
>
> - Connect & Query SQL Server
> - Connect & Query Azure SQL Database
> - Connect & Query Azure Data Warehouse

And from [Github SQL Operations Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio)

> SQL Operations Studio is a data management tool **that enables working with SQL Server, Azure SQL DB and SQL DW** from Windows, macOS and Linux.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to migrate mysql database to one of those formats